# Application of AM/GM inequality

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If we have $20$ real positive number $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{20}$ then how do I prove that $\frac{a_1}{a_4} + \frac{a_2}{a_5} + \ldots + \frac{a_{18}}{a_1}+ \frac{a_{19}}{a_2}+\frac{a_{20}}{a_3} \gt 20$.

Comment: Just apply AM-GM, noting that the product of all the fractions is $1$.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? the product of all the fraction is 1, but how do I use am-gm to prove it? isn't am-gm mean that the additive porduct is greater than the geometic product. How does that apply

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The product of the terms is $1$. Use the Arithmetic Mean/ Geometric Mean Inequality.

Comment: what do you mean the product of the term is 1. as in a1/a4 * a2/5 etc is 1?

Comment: Every $a_i$ occurs once in a numerator and once in a denominator.

Comment: okay, so how do I use arithmetic mean/gometric mean inequality? I know that arithmetic mean/geometric mean inequality mean that the the arithmetic mean is greater than the geometric mean.

Comment: The product of the terms is $\frac{a_1a_2a_3a_4\cdots a_{20}}{a^4a_5\cdots a_{20}a_1a_2a_3}$. Everything cancels, we get $1$.

Comment: To use AM/GM, let our fractions be $x_1$ to $x_{20}$. Then by AM/GM we have $\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_{20}}{20}\ge (x_1x_2\cdots x_{20})^{1/20}=1$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So if I understand it correctly. so since we know that the multiplication/geometric means of these fractions are greater than 1. then the summation of these fraction/20 must be greater than or equal to 1. So then you times 20 and you get that the summation of these fraction are greater than 20

Comment: There is a typo in my comment two above this one, The $a^4$ should be $a_4$.

Comment: okay, Thank you so much

Comment: What you wrote above is right, except for a couple of times when you write greater instead of $\ge$. Note that we get equality for example when all the $a_i$ are $1$.